Verify the correctness of a circuit: AC to DC conversion for Arduino Nano and relays
I need your opinion about the correctness of my circuit. As is shown in the drawing schematic, the circuit is supplied by 220 VAC which will be converted to 12 VDC. This output is used to supply the Arduino Nano shown in the first figure and relay 2, while relay 1 is supplied by the same 22O VAC. Am I correct? Both relays are controlled by the same condition.



the top diagram is missing the 220 Vac load ... right now the relay #1 contacts short out the AC power ... similarly for the 12 Vdc and relay #2

Explain more please , indeed the 220VAC for the relay is fed into the circuit through the terminal of the 3 inputs attached to the relay , while for the second relay , we directly fed the 12 BDC tension

"Explain more please", switch (and relay) is supposed to connect in serial to a power source to switch on/off the power, not in parallel to the power source to short it. You learn this in secondary school. If you don't even understand that, you shouldn't mess with AC...

Ah true, i did this mistake where i was drawing, i edited it now, what do you think ?

You are using 12V input to Arduino, and using it as 5V supply regulator for huge loads such as a 5V relay. The design is correct in theory but you don't seem to care about if it can be done in practice. How much current is each 5V relay? Why are you not using a 12V relay to begin with?

U meant that I have to supply the relay with 12V instead of 5V ?
